# How do you allocate memory for a 2D array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, image-processing, visual-studio-2013

hey I want to allocate some memory for a 2D array and free it later in C++
I want to do this as I am getting an Error in my program " EXPRESSION MUST HAVE A CONSTANT VALUE.

int x = height;

```
int y = width;

int pixelArray[x][y];
```

Thank you.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: std::vector<std::vector<int>> pixelArray(height, std::vector<int>(width));

Comment: You are getting that error because array size has to be a constant, the compiler needs to know it at compile time. If you need a variable sized array you will need to assign it using new and delete. `int** pixelArray = new int[x][y]` . Beware that the usage of new and delete is not a good programming practice. Always use smart pointers.

Comment: I'm just curious, why do you think it's important that you're "using Visual Studio 2013"? Do you really believe that core features of C++, like this, depend on the compiler being used? It may come as a shock for some, but the whole reason that languages like C++ are standardized is so that the core parts of this technology will work the same with any compliant compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The naive approach is to allocate one array to contain row pointers, and then allocate every single row, but this can lead to poor performance of your array due to memory locality.  It also cannot be used in the same way as a fixed-size 2D array, which is contiguous in memory.

So what you can do is allocate one block of integers to hold all the data, and one array of pointers to index it.

```
int ** my_array = new int*[ x ];
my_array[0] = new int[ x * y ];
for( int i = 1; i < x; i++ )
{
    my_array[i] = my_array[i-1] + y;
}
```

To clean up, you do this:

```
delete [] my_array[0];
delete [] my_array;
```

You should consider wrapping this functionality into a simple class, since it is maintaining more than one pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Since x and y are variables, you have to dynamically allocate the array using new.  You can initialize a 2D array as follows:

```
int ** pixelArray = new int*[x];
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  pixelArray[i] = new int[y];
}
```

And you dispose of it in the following way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  delete[] pixelArray[i];
}
delete[] pixelArray;
```